# Developing .Net app and embed in CD

Tags: c#, sql, deployment

I have an application (Stand alone app) , that basically reads & writes data with UI . And i have to embed it in CD and make it auto-run.

But i have few confusions , needs your help for the same

1. Whether to choose Windows or web application of .Net?
2. Which Data Storage mechanism is preferable ?
3. How to handle the DB part , since app will be CD how to write the data.

Thanks

Comment: Some idea of what the app does may help us answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can't run a web application from a CD.  You probably want to use a Windows application.
2. You seem to be assuming a database, so I'd guess your storage mechanism is to use a database.  Look at the data you need to store and how you need to use it, and make a decision based on that.
3. You can't write to a CD.  You need to either write to a known location (say, the `AppData` folder) or ask the user to specify one in your application.

Also worth noting: you can't auto-run an application any more (since Windows 7, and I believe back-ported to Vista).  The best you can do is have the auto-run dialogue include an *option* to run your application.

Comment: Thank You for your Valuable suggestion.